# The building seemed collapsed or collapsing

Tags: vocabulary

After long research, though the verb (collapse) is an intransitive verb, I have found out that I can say “a collapsed building”. «Collapse» is used as a past participle (adjective).
My question is, should I say ”the building seemed collapsed" as collapsed is used here as an adjective?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should say *The building seemed **to have collapsed*** if the collapse has already happened, or *...seemed **to be collapsing*** if it's an ongoing process. Your versions are both "syntactically valid" (and would make the same *semantic* distinction), but they're idiomatically "unusual / awkward", and wouldn't normally be used by native speakers.

Comment: ...note that we don't often refer to "a collapsed building" anyway, because once it's collapsed, it's no longer a "building". It's ***a pile of rubble***, or just ***ruins***.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but not very natural.  There may be some debate about whether "A collapsed building" actually has an adjective, or whether there is a one-word participle clause  "collapsed".  Past participles are not actually adjectives, they are a form of a verb.

There is a simple way to express this, by using an infinitive phrase (here in the perfective aspect)

> The building seemed to have collapsed.